# CSS Slide Elements Into Page on Hover

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I have a the footer of my page structured like so:

```
            <div class="footer-header-links">
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-hidden-links">
                <a href="#">Overview</a><a href="#">Mission & Vision</a><a href="#">Team</a><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
```

It looks like:

[image]

The CSS is as following:

I want to hide the links (Overview, Mission & Vision etc.) and only display them if there is a click or hover on 'About Us' - I am unable to figure out how to do this.

Another thing I want to do is slide these links in from the left when About Us is clicked instead of just fading them into the page.

Hoping to find a CSS Solution.

Answer (score 0):

below is the code to do same, try this

```
<div class="footer-header-links">
    <a href="#" class="aboutUs">About Us</a>
</div>

<div class="footer-hidden-links">
    <a href="#" class="showOnHover">Overview</a>
    <a href="#" class="showOnHover">Mission & Vision</a>
    <a href="#">Team</a></br>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a></br>
</div>


.showOnHover {
    display: none;
}
.footer-header-links:hover +.footer-hidden-links .showOnHover{
   display`enter code here`: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Using that I am able to hide and unhide the links, can you help me figure out a CSS transition where the links slide into view from the left?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve fade in on hover, you could use something along the lines of the following:

```
.footer-hidden-links{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.footer-header-links:hover~.footer-hidden-links{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The CSS3 transition property could also be used to slide your elements in from the left (with some tweaks to make your styling positional)

transition: left 1s;